# Linux user-space application compilation error

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, makefile

I am a newbie to linux kernel/system development.

Below is the Makefile i am using to compile my application

```
CROSS_COMPILE   ?=
KERNEL_DIR  ?= /usr/src/linux

CC      := $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
KERNEL_INCLUDE  := -I/usr/include
CFLAGS      := -W -Wall -g $(KERNEL_INCLUDE)
LDFLAGS     := -g

all: finder-drv

finder-drv: finder.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f finder
```

I am getting the following the error:

```
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabi/sys/ioctl.h:22:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why the features.h is missing.

This problem came after i run the following command:

```
make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix the issue and correctly link/use kernel header files in a user-space appliation?

Comment: Why are you including something from "arm" while your architecture is x86?

Comment: Shahbaz: My architecture is ARM. I am not using the ARCH variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved.

The correct command to export kernel headers for user-space application is below

> make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr/include

I have given `/usr` instead of `/usr/include`

I recovered the deleted files in `/usr/include` by reinstalling the `libc-dev` using the following command

> apt-get install lib6-dev --reinstall

Chris, Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Glad you have a solution.  Though unless you have made unique changes to the kernel's interface to userspace you should not need to re-export the headers - 'sudo apt-get install build-essential' should get you everything (tools, includes, etc) needed to build basic userspace applications on Ubuntu.

Comment: Chris, This is first time i am doing Linux system/kernel programming. So i am just experimenting and learning the things.

Comment: You mean: apt-get install libc-dev --reinstall

Answer (score 2):

Compiling userspace programs directly against the kernel is not intended to work.

If you are writing a userspace program, you compile against the exported headers, and use only exported functionality such as syscalls.  Likely you go through proxies provided by the C library.

If you are writing a kernel module, you should use the kernel build system rather than craft your own makefile.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am writing a userspace program. Earlier when i compiling my application, i got some header files not found issues. So i tried to export the kernel headers to userspace by using make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr but everything is messed up after this command. Things that are working earlier are not working now. Can you please suggest a remedy?

Comment: If you are finding missing headers, it's likely you either have a program not intended for a modern linux, haven't identified the proper headers within the existing include paths, or are trying to use functionality which is not available to userspace programs.  You also seem to have a broken mix of a host include path /usr/include with a cross toolchain.  Can you find a 'hello world' or whatever demo project known to work with your target platform's toolchain?

Comment: Chris, things are working except the above described problem. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 on pandaboard es with kernel version 3.1. I build kernel module on daily basis without a single error. Actually the code with which i am having problems is 1+ year old. But the thing that worry me is that the header files used in problematic code are also used in my kernel module and the module build successfully. I got problems after "make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr". Can you please tell/guide me how can i reset kernel headers and other things to clean state. headers reinstal/install didn't worked

Comment: The headers you use in a kernel module should not overlap with those you use in userspace - they are extremely different execution and thus programming environments.  A few headers might have the same name in kernel and userspace, but should be coming from different directory paths because they are different internally for each.  Can you build the application to run on the development machine as a test, or actually compile it on the arm board, to get the cross compilation complications temporarily out of the picture?

Comment: I am using board as development machine and building the application on it.

Comment: If you are running the compiler on the target system, you need to get all the cross stuff out of your makefile - it would be just like building for a desktop linux.

Comment: Chris, Great Thanks for your time and help. But still same issue. I tried to compile the application directly with gcc bypassing the makefile, but getting same issue. Now i will try to setup the new environment or will see how can i clean the header files mess without new env.

Comment: You should first succesfully compile a simple userspace program with a simple makefile.  Then move to your project, with rthe same simple makefile.  If you get errors related to includes, check the man pages for the functions on which you got errors; these will tell you the proper includes they require.